# why link database tables?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a DB model that uses several tables to hold business logic data; one of the tables includes a user table that hold the UserID. The code reads data from these tables and generates a json string that's used in the application. To avoid having to redo the queries and recreating the json string, I store the json string in a table call JsonCache that has only 2 columns: UserID and JsonCacheWork. Each user has multiple JsonCacheWork entries (entries add themselves as the result of user interactions).

For the moment, there are no relationships on my database diagram between the User table and the JsonCache table. It seems to work fine.

Why would I need/want to add relationships between the 2 tables and what are the advantags, if any, of keeping my DB diagram as is.

Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: By "database diagram", do you mean the dataset designer, the database diagram in the Visual Studio Server Explorer, the database diagram in SSMS, or something else?

Comment: @ChrisShain: the linq-to-sql ORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the relationship between tables to tell the database management system that the records in those two tables are related. DMS can enforce this relationship, which means that you won't make a mistake of adding a record to JsonCache table with UserId that doesn't exist.

Also, the foreign key constraint can be used to automatically delete records in one table when a related record in the other table is deleted (cascade deletes). So when you delete a user the DMS will delete his entry in JsonCache for you.

Sql Server is a *relational* database and relations between tables are key part of database schema. They help maintaining data integrity.

Comment: There is a difference between relations and relationships.

Comment: @frenchie: Only slightly. Any relationship or other constraint means a slight performance decrease to be enforced. But you lose integrity without them.

Comment: How is integrity lost?  If it's one to one, and you'll only select a JSON with the given user ID, I see no reason to have a separate table instead of a mere column.  No normalization rule is broken that I know of.

Comment: @duffymo - I'm not talking just about this example (you're right that another column in Users table will suffice). I'm just trying to explain what relations are for in general.

Comment: I'm not questioning you; I'm disagreeing with the "loss of integrity" statement.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to have a join table between the two if there was a many-to-many relationship between the two entities.  I would say that since user and the JSON are one-to-one, I'd question using two separate entities.  I'd put the JSON in the user table and simply query for it by user ID.  I don't see a reason for the separate table with two columns just for the JSON.

I might change my mind if the JSON had a shelf life: effective and expiration dates, history for a single user, etc.

Comment: What happens is that the json strings are deleted when the user logs off so in essence, the table is pretty small since it only contains data of the logged-in users. Each user will have multiple records in that cache table so I need to put the data in a different table (ie. not the user table).